# How can you access audio files saved on an iPhone using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to make an application on the iPhone using PhoneGap. I know that you can access photos stored in the phone's photo library using navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY. Is there an equivalent of this for accessing audio files on the phone? I've looked through the documentation for PhoneGap, but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly iOS give us the limited access to the media files . By  navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY you can only access the camera roll. you cant access the pre stored video also using this code . SO i don't think you can access the audio files stored in the iPhone by using any way .

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking. Thank you for letting me know!